# Getting portlet session in JS

Tags: javascript, session, portlet

Hi I am trying to fetch portlet session in my JS variable. How could I go about it

```
 request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("countryList");  //This is my .java class code
```

I need to fetch the same in JS?

Answer (score 3):

you can't access to java session via javascript.

One solution is to serialize you java object into json string and save it into session(if object is null, just save a string that equals to "null")

```
getPortletSession().setAttribute("countryListJson", JSONUtil.toJSON(yourObject));
```

then you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = <%=request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("countryListJson")%>;
</script>
```

Another solution is to provide a json padding controller method for ajax call. and return a string like this :

```
return "var countryList = " + JsonUtil.toJson(request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("countryList")) +";"
```

then you should mapping this method to a url such as "/contryList.do"
and in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/contryList.do"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(contryList);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you need to place in some JS var the countryList (from controller). You don't need to get portlet session in JS, you should be able to do like follows:

I managed to get some strings from controller to js using scriptlets and usebean. Try something like this:

Let's say i need to alert an error from backend and i have put it in a java string named "error"(in controller).
I'm able to do this(doView):

```
String error = request.getAttribute("error"); // or it can be simply String error = "sometext"
if ((error != null) || (!error.equals(""))){
request.setAttribute("error", error);

}
else request.setAttribute("error","false");
```

Then, in your jsp, at the top i'll place an usebean tag like:

```
<jsp:useBean id="error" class="java.lang.String" scope="request"></jsp:useBean>
```

Then, between script tags:

```
var error = "<%=error%>";
if (error != "false") alert(error);
```

As i noticed, you need to set the var in controller (with setAttribute) using an if / else statement.